# Unable to parse the xhtml document on linux

Tags: java, windows, linux, parsing, xhtml

I am trying to parse a xhtml wellformed document using DocumentBuilder, The requirement is i will parse xhtml document and i will append the content to the body part of the xhtml document. For parsing the document i am using the below code

```
org.w3c.dom.Document document=null; 
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(false);   
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
document=builder.parse(file);
```

The fileis the xhtml file i want to parse
its working fine on windows machine, when i am trying to run the same code on linux machine its failing to parse the document and giving the exception

```
java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:723)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:589)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:720)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:589)
```

Can anybody help me why its not working on linux machine.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

What comes into my mind is that the parser is trying to get the schema from HTTP server. Could you try to disable validation:

factory.setValidating(false)

Or ensure that you can properly download the schemas in your document with wget command (not browser).

Comment: I have added factory.setValidating(false); still does not working.

Comment: Could you please provide the code line on which exception occurs and just in case try to download your schemas with wget

Comment: document=builder.parse(file);, at this line i am getting the exception. i dont know about wget why its used for?